# How to skip anchor tag and refresh button when onbeforeunload calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to popup a message says that "you are not loged out" when user tries to close browser. I use bellow code for that.

```
var popupMessgae = true;
 window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
      if(popupMessgae == true) {
           popupMessgae = false;
           return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; 
      }
 }
```

but it also popup message when I click on anchor tag and try to refresh page.I don't want that..There should be a way to handle this situation, please help me to know that.

Thank you

Comment: `onbeforeunload` happens every time a page is unloaded. There is no way to detect if this is because the user is going to another page on your site, another site completely or closing the browser/tab. In other words, what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: is not there any way to disclude anchor tags ? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

For the anchor tags you could try this in jQuery

```
$('a[name]').onclick( function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

As was suggested here [Can I prevent onbeforeunload from being called when clicking on an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742241/can-i-prevent-onbeforeunload-from-being-called-when-clicking-on-an-anchor-tag)